# Divs stack with 3d effect

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create 3d like animation for building and floors.

This is my initial design idea.
I want to create this divs with 3d effects and possible some animation on hover to recognize the current div.
I have never done animation or worked with 3d css effects so your help is much appreciated

Thanks in advance !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Im thinking that you could likely increase the z-index in css to make it appear on top of other elements.

Comment: well how do I make those div look like 3d ?

Comment: You could use the box-shadow to make a 3dish shadow effect. and by layering divs on top of each other you can make it seem more 3d, but full 3d isnt really possible afaik without THREEJS. You could change the rotation of the div tho in 3d.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you: https://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/GRYZaxJ

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="stack">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```scss
$div-count: 30;

@function randomc($saturation: 100%, $lightness: 50%) {
  $hue: random(360);
  @return hsl($hue, $saturation, $lightness);
}


.wrapper {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;

  .box {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .stack {
    display: block;
    perspective: 1500px;
    perspective-origin: -200% center;
    transform: translateX(-5px) translateY(-100%);
    transition: all 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  
    .card {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid;
      z-index: 1;
      background-color: white;
      transition: all 0.5s;
  
      @for $i from 1 through $div-count {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
          top: 0;
          z-index: $div-count - $i;
          border-color: randomc();
        }
      }

      &:nth-child(1) {
        transform: rotateZ(10deg);
      }

      @for $i from 2 through $div-count {
        &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
          transform: rotateZ(20deg);
        }
      }
    }  
  }

  &:hover {
    .stack {
      perspective-origin: -400% center;
      transform: translateX(-15px) translateY(-65px) rotateZ(0deg);

      .card {
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);

        @for $i from 1 through $div-count {
          &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
            top: ($i - 1) * 15px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```